# Transpose of the matrix

Tags: matrices

From the school days I have learnt that transpose of a matrix is the rows and columns inverted but that is the how of the question, I need to learn why of the question. What is its significance and why we need to do that?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Transpose_of_a_linear_map.

Answer (score 1):

A more elementary answer to your question than the Wikipedia link on dual spaces is this. Working with an $m\times n$ *real* matrix $A$, let $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and $y\in\Bbb R^m$. Then you have the fundamental equation
$$Ax\cdot y = x\cdot A^\top y.$$
(The dot product on the left is computed in $\Bbb R^m$; the dot product on the right is computed in $\Bbb R^n$.) This is not difficult to see if you interpret the dot product $x\cdot y$ as the $1\times 1$ matrix $x^\top y$ and use basic properties of matrix transpose.